# Parallelization/threads inside a web request in Scala/Java?

Tags: web-services, scala, parallel-processing, akka

I have a webservice that is doing a number of database queries (to MongoDB) and then doing a non-trivial amount of processing on the records returned by those database queries. Each web request needs to run about 15-45 of these requests which is causing unacceptable page response times as each query + processing takes about 20ms. Caching will not work as the cache-miss rate will be high and data needs to be as fresh as possible.

I had planned on using Scala + Akka and actors to parallelize the class executing and processing the queries but I know creating threads inside a servlet container is discouraged. What is the recommended way of doing threading/parallelization inside a web request in Scala?

Comment: I'm not answering your question because, if you can't have more than one thread, I have no idea how you're parallelize anything.  What I would say is that using Akka Actors would probably not be a great idea. Akka Futures would be the way to go here.

Comment: @Derek I think that's my question, is it ok to use Actors in my code inside a web request in Scala + Akka? I want to have more than one thread, wrapping the class that does the query and processing in an Actor. I'm considering Futures but also wanted to know if I could use Actors.

Comment: I've successfully written highly reliable and scalable applications with Mist - the HTTP add-on in Akka that puts an Actor shim in between your business logic and the Web Container.  So I don't see why there is any problem with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see why you can't use Akka's Futures for this (I'm using the 2.0 SNAPSHOT).

```
import akka.dispatch.Future
Future.sequence(1 to 45 map { i =>
  Future {
    ... make database query i ...
  }
}) onComplete { future =>
  future.result.map { resultList =>
    // resultList.foldLeft...
    // resultList.map...
    // resultList.foreach...
    // resultList.whatever...
  }
}
```

(And there's certainly more than one way to deal with Futures in Akka to suit your needs.  That example may not be ideal for what you want)

Have a look at the excellent Akka documentation for more info:  [Akka 1.2R6 Future documentation](http://akka.io/docs/akka/1.2-RC6/scala/futures.html)

As I mentioned in the comments above, I've used [the Akka HTTP module](http://akka.io/docs/akka/1.2-RC6/scala/http.html) to build highly scalable and reliable apps in the past, and they're all Actor / Future based.